# Blender: call custom menu action from script

Tags: python, blender, bpy

I'm using Blender 2.80 with an add-on (not developed by me). This add-on add some new functionalities and allow the user to export the scene with a custom extension (to do this it add a new option in File --> Export).

Now I'm developing a new python script able to open a new blender scene, make some actions and then save it using that custom extension but I don't know how to call a custom export option.

Briefly this is what I've done till now:

```
import os
import bpy

bpy.ops.wm.open_mainfile(filepath="path//to//file.blend")

# some actions...

# not what I want since this export the scene as obj file...
bpy.ops.export_scene.obj(filepath="path//to//target.obj")
```

Answer (score 0):

in the preferences enable "Python Tooltips" and "Developer Extras".

then go to the "file > Export" and hover cursor over that menu entry. it will tell you operator call.

you can use that call in script to run it.